# How to change the parent layout in HerbstluftWM?

Tags: window-manager, layout

I would like to switch layouts from horizontal to vertical in herbstluftwm like follows

from:

```
╾─┐ horizontal 50% selection=1
  ├─╼ horizontal: 0xa0000e
  └─╼ horizontal: 0x2a0000e [FOCUS]
```

to the following:

```
╾─┐ vertical 50% selection=1
  ├─╼ horizontal: 0xa0000e
  └─╼ horizontal: 0x2a0000e [FOCUS]
```

If I change the layout by using the command `herbstclient set_layout vertical` it only is applied for the currently selected window:

```
╾─┐ horizontal 50% selection=1
  ├─╼ horizontal: 0xa0000e
  └─╼ vertical: 0x2a0000e [FOCUS]  <--------turns vertical here
```

But I would like to get

```
╾─┐ vertical 50% selection=1 <--------turns vertical here
  ├─╼ horizontal: 0xa0000e
  └─╼ horizontal: 0x2a0000e [FOCUS]
```

I couldn't find a way to focus the parent node (=frame?) to perform the layout-setting on it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer half of the question:

To switch from horizontal to vertical layout (or vice versa) one can simply use

```
herbstclient rotate
```

This switches between both layouts.

However specifically focusing the parent node (it is actually called **root frame**) I'm still searching for a way to do this.